# I send an image to my server but when stored at the server it is not readable

Tags: javascript, java, spring

When I have uploaded my image to the server it is not readable. I have also implemented a file upload feature that works. It had the same server implementation as when sending an image.

My investigations indicates that it is a file coding conversion that I need to do somewhere.

I use "canvas.toDataUrl" to get an image of png type. That image is then sent to the server that expects a "MultipartFile"
How can I convert the "image" to a "MultiPartFile" format, or if you have another suggestions? It is not necessary to reuse the java code but I did it since it was convenient when I started.

Some pats of my javascript code below.

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var formData = new FormData();
var blob = new Blob([image.src], {type:"image/png"} );
formData.append("file", blob, "myfile.png"); 
formData.append("enctype", "multipart/form-data");

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "/upload );
request.send(formData);
```

Some parts of the java `spring.io` code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload")
public  String handleFileUpload(HttpServletRequest request, Principal            
                                currentUser, Model model,
                                @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
  {
     String imgsrc;
     imgsrc = "/home/myfile.png";

     byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
     BufferedOutputStream stream =
             new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(imgsrc)));
     stream.write(bytes);
     stream.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I found how to solve it. It is not yet optimized, I would like to avoid copying the byte array.

First I looked at the file in the console. It starts with:

data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE

And I also read that it was a DOMString that was returned på canvas.toDataURL

Before storing the file I removed the first characters that is not the image, in this case it is all characters until "base64," that I removed.

From the heading I guessed that it is base64 encoded string so before storing the file I decoded the rest of the data. The decoder I use is java.util.Base64.Decoder

I did this at the server side in Java. The rows looks like this:

```
byte[] withoutInitialCharacters = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, 22, bytes.length );
Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decode(withoutInitialCharacters);
```